# What enabled the spread of virtual reality systems?

Tags: discoveries, technology

What new technology enabled us to construct VR recently? Was it just the resolution which makes believable image?

Comment: Wikipedia has a very detailed answer to this already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_reality

Comment: @Conifold I checked it out before but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: From what I read there it was a combination of things, including more powerful computers and AI algorithms, not a single magic bullet.